# Personal resume and project site using React

Tags: beginner, ecmascript-6, react.js, jsx

Recently, I enrolled in the React Fundamentals course by Tyler McGinnis, and afterwards, I decided to rewrite my personal site to entirely run with ES6 React. Since I'm really new at this, I was wondering if anyone could have a quick glance at the code and structuring of the app?

http://github.com/pestbarn/pestbarn.github.io

It's written using React Router's hashHistory, so that I can run the app directly on Github Pages - http://www.mattias.pw

**Structure**

```
├── CNAME
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── Index.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Aside.js
│   │   ├── ConfirmSent.js
│   │   ├── Contact.js
│   │   ├── ContactForm.js
│   │   ├── ExperienceList.js
│   │   ├── Index.js
│   │   ├── Locator.js
│   │   ├── Logo.js
│   │   ├── Pendulum.js
│   │   ├── Root.js
│   │   ├── Stats.js
│   │   ├── StatsBeer.js
│   │   └── StatsGigs.js
│   ├── config
│   │   └── Router.js
│   ├── containers
│   │   ├── DefaultContainer.js
│   │   ├── Index.js
│   │   └── StatsContainer.js
│   └── index.html
├── bin
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   └── js
│       └── main.js
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── robots.txt
├── src
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   ├── logo_paths.svg
│   │   ├── paper.jpg
│   │   └── profile.jpg
│   └── postcss
│       ├── _h5bp.postcss
│       ├── animations.postcss
│       ├── base.postcss
│       ├── main.postcss
│       └── variables.postcss
├── stats
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── sorttable.min.js
│   └── stats.css
└── webpack.config.js
```

**`/webpack.config.js`**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: __dirname + '/index.html',
    inject: true
});

module.exports = [
    {
        entry: [
            './app/Index.js'
        ],
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'main.js',
            path: __dirname + '/bin/js'
        },
        plugins: [
            HTMLWebpackPluginConfig
        ]
    },
    {
        entry: [
            './src/postcss/base.postcss'
        ],
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.postcss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1!resolve-url-loader!postcss-loader?sourceMap=inline'
                    })
                }, {
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                    loaders: [
                        'file-loader?emitFile=false&name=[path][name].[ext]'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('./main.css'),
        ],
        output: {
            filename: 'main.css',
            path: __dirname + '/bin/css'
        }
    }
];
```

**`/app/Index.js`**

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './config/Router.js';

const app = document.getElementById('app');

render(
    Routes,
    app
);
```

**`/app/components/Index.js`**

Index file for making importing modules a bit simpler.

```
import Aside from './Aside';
import ConfirmSent from './ConfirmSent';
import Contact from './Contact';
import ContactForm from './ContactForm';
import ExperienceList from './ExperienceList';
import Locator from './Locator';
import Logo from './Logo';
import Pendulum from './Pendulum';
import Root from './Root';
import Stats from './Stats';
import StatsBeer from './StatsBeer';
import StatsGigs from './StatsGigs';

export {
    Aside,
    ConfirmSent,
    Contact,
    ContactForm,
    ExperienceList,
    Locator,
    Logo,
    Pendulum,
    Root,
    Stats,
    StatsBeer,
    StatsGigs
};
```

**`/app/components/Root.js`**

Root file with order of components visible on the site's index.html page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Experience, Header } from '../containers/';
import { Aside, Contact, ContactForm, ExperienceList, Logo, Pendulum } from './';

class Root extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="root-container">
                <Header locator={true}>
                    <Logo />
                </Header>
                <Contact />
                <ContactForm />
                <Aside />
                <Experience>
                    <Pendulum />
                    <ExperienceList />
                </Experience>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Root;
```

**`/app/components/Aside.js`**

Example of how I've structured my components, with some calculations and some JSX.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Aside extends React.Component {
    calcAge(date) {
        const today = new Date();
        const month = ((today.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (today.getMonth() + 1);
        const day = (today.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + today.getDate();

        let now = [
            today.getFullYear(),
            month,
            day
        ];

        now = now.join('');

        let age = (now - date).toString();
        return parseInt(age.slice(0,2));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <aside>
                <p>
                    <strong>
                        Mattias Hagberg
                    </strong>
                    <br />
                    <time>{this.calcAge(19890125)}</time>, male, Uppsala
                    <br />
                    Frontend developer
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>
                        projects / contact channels
                    </strong>
                    <br />
                    <a href="http://www.mattias.pw/starburst.css">starburst.css</a>
                    ,
                    <a href="http://codepen.io/pestbarn/pens/public/">things</a>
                    ,
                    <Link to="/stats">stats</Link>
                    <br />
                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/pestbarn">linkedin</a>
                    ,
                    <a href="http://github.com/pestbarn">github</a>
                    ,
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/@pestbarn">twitter</a>
                </p>
                <img src="/src/img/profile.jpg" />
            </aside>
        );
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track? Are there any best practices I'm missing or should think about?